# Sort list of paths by file basename (Python)

Tags: python, sorting

I have a folder with images.
I added to a list the paths for each image. They are not alphabetically sorted.
I made this function to sort but I the result it's the same when I print the list after sorting.

```
import os
import glob

images_path = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\samples\\')

def img_path_list():
    img_list = []
    for file_path in glob.glob(str(images_path) + "*.jpg"):
        img_list.append(file_path)

    img_list.sort(key=lambda x: str(x.split('.')[0]))

    return img_list

print(img_path_list())
```

The result it's still i.e: `[Desktop\\t0.jpg, Desktop\\t1.jpg, Desktop\\t10.jpg, Desktop\\t11.jpg, Desktop\\t2.jpg, ...]`

EDIT: not a duplicate as long as I didn't request to use `natsort` module but with simple python.

Comment: The result looks very sorted to me.

You want to have t2.jpg before t10.jpg?

Comment: The result is an example. Yes, normal sorting. 123 instead of 1, 10, 2, 20, etc..

Comment: `EDIT: ...` sorry but your restrictions aren't our concern.

Comment: Understand that you're looking to naturally sort on something. Whether you asked for an external module or not, that question has been asked before. So it is a duplicate, regardless of whether this is your homework or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `os.path.basename` and assuming your filenames are all of the format `X#.jpg` with `X` a single character:

```
import os

img_list = ['Desktop\\t0.jpg', 'Desktop\\t1.jpg',
            'Desktop\\t10.jpg', 'Desktop\\t11.jpg',
            'Desktop\\t2.jpg']

img_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(os.path.basename(x).split('.')[0][1:]))

print(img_list)

['Desktop\\t0.jpg', 'Desktop\\t1.jpg',
 'Desktop\\t2.jpg', 'Desktop\\t10.jpg',
 'Desktop\\t11.jpg']
```

With a named function to illustrate how `lambda` works:

```
def sorter(x):
    return int(os.path.basename(x).split('.')[0][1:])

img_list.sort(key=sorter)
```

**Explanation**

There are a few steps here:

1. Extract the filename via `os.path.basename`.
2. Split by `.` and extract first element.
3. Then slice by 1st character onwards.
4. Convert the result to `int` for numerical ordering.

Comment: That's the answer. Still have to learn about lamba function and how it works.

Comment: @Link, `lambda` is just an anonymous function. I'll give an equivalent example with a named function.

Comment: Very good. Thanks again.